# where exists SQL not working properly - H2 Db

Tags: sql, select, h2

I am trying to select permissions that are only part of a specific permission group. They are binned together in a relational table. The way I am trying to this is by using WHERE EXISTS in a sub query.

```
select * 
from permissions 
where exists (select 'x' 
              from rel_sets_permission 
              where pset_id = :id);
```

The problem is that it seems like that if there is at least one occurrence of the id in the relational table, I will get as a result of main query all of the permissions.
I need advice, as I have looked up the logic of the WHERE EXISTS and its purpose should be the case in which I use it.
I am working with H2 database.

Comment: You need a correlation clause in the subquery.  Without know what the tables look like, it is hard to make further suggestions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well permission has many attributes while relation table has only its own surrogate id, permission id and permission Set id.

Comment: `select a,b,c from X where exists (select 1 from Y WHERE Y.p=X.d);`

Comment: Adding to wildplasser's good comment, either pset_id or :id need to be from the permissions table.  You really should be explicit about that too: select * from permissions where exists (select 'x' from rel_sets_permission where rel_sets_permission.pset_id = permissions.id);

Comment: @wildplasser this worked perfectly, Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the problem is as stated in comments. Just added a correlation clause in addition to the subquery.

Something of form

```
WHERE rel_sets_permission.pset_id = permissions.id
```